# Comparison of forward and flyback converters in terms of losses

Tags: dc-dc-converter

If you read comparisons of different topologies in the context of power, you may notice that forward converters are usually recommended for higher power levels compared to flyback converters.

Could you please check my reasoning: one of the reasons for this lies in the transformer design. In a flyback converter, ALL the output energy is "accumulated" in the transformer, resulting in high core losses due to magnetization.

In a forward converter, all the energy goes directly to the secondary winding where it then goes to the rectifier and LC filter.

But in this reasoning, I still don't understand this... because in a forward converter, all the losses associated with core magnetization have been transferred from the transformer to the inductance, and in total, we should get the same losses.

Can you help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a forward convertor we will choose to make primary and secondary inductances much higher than that used for a flyback converter hence, magnetisation and core losses are much less for the same power transfer.

You increase inductance by increasing the turns. So, if you double the turns, the inductance rises four times (it's a square thing). This means your magnetization current reduces by 4. This means that your flux ampere-turns reduce by two and, as a result the maximum flux density halves.

That's why we use more turns in a forward converter and why the energy stored in the magnetic field is very much less than for a flyback converter.

So, why don't we always use a forward convertor? Answer: because flyback converters are simpler and easier to design.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy stated in his answer, the primary (magnetising) inductance of a forward converter's transformer is usually much higher than that of a flyback converter for the same power levels and switching frequency. This brings lower magnetising currents and therefore lower losses.

A flyback converter transformer is a store-and-transfer thing i.e. the energy is stored in the primary magnetic field and then transferred to the secondary *(Energy storage and transfer are done by the secondary-side choke in a forward converter as it operates just like a buck)*. This requires an air gap, and the presence of an air gap basically means loss (Research terms here: Eddy current loss, proximity effect, proximity loss). An air gap is not necessarily needed in a forward converter.